# How to get the original text of a sentence after CoreNLP does ssplit?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Tokenization by CoreNLP changes the sentence text. Stitching together tokens separated by white space isn't a true reconstruction. Things get complicated if the sentence contains round brackets and other punctuation. Please see the code block below.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation document = new Annotation(paragraph);
pipeline.annotate(document);

List<CoreMap>sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

List<String> sentenceList = new ArrayList<>();
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) 
{
    //How to get the original text of sentence?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. Its pretty easy. Insert the following line in place of the comment in the question code block.

```
String sentenceString = Sentence.listToOriginalTextString(sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) 
{
    String sentenceStr = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class)
}
```